# Unable to see Codename One Initializer in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to Codename one. I installed the IntelliJ plugin, but I can't see it when I try to create a new project.

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the large image, unable to find a way to size it down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the plugin and there's no integration of our initializer into the IDE other than the standard Maven integration. To use it just go to https://start.codenameone.com/ and enter the details. Then download the resulting application and open it in IntelliJ/IDEA.